# Why is my css grid not centring when I make my width aspect ratio smaller?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am in the process of making my first responsive webpage. Although it is exciting, I am running into some issues. Here is the main one. As I make my aspect width smaller, my css grid becomes more and more off center. I have looked over my code but I have no idea what is causing the issue. (Ignore the unresponsive navigation bar, I have yet to make one for mobile yet.)
Thanks!

```css
html{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.center{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%); 
}

#hero{
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 0.3%;
    background: rgb(14,39,79);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(14,39,79,1) 0%, rgb(25, 58, 110) 100%);    
    width: 98.5%;
    height: 94%;
    text-align: center;
}

#navBar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 2% 8% 0% 8%;

}

.logo{
    width: 18%;
    height: 18%;
}

li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.page{
    color: white;
}

.otherPages{
    color: #dadada;
    transition: 200ms linear;
}

.otherPages:hover{
    color: white;
}

.bookNow{
    margin-right: 8%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav__links{
    list-style: none;
}

.nav__links li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.bookNowNav{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2.5px solid white;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: 200ms linear;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.bookNowNav:hover{
    background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.5);
}

button{
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 7.5rem;
    height: 3rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

h1{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 400%;
    display: flex;
    place-content: center;
    margin-top: 8vh;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 0px ;
}

p{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.darker-text{
    color: #d5d3db;
}

.container{
    width: 84vw;
}

.grid-gallery {
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 88vh;
    width: 100%;
    height: 920px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      'header header header header header header'
      'menu main main main right right'
      'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
    grid-gap: 20px;
    padding: 10px;    
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
.grid-gallery > div {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  

.item1 { 
    grid-area: header;
    background-image: url(./images/DJI_0344-Enhanced\ copy.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.item2 { 
    grid-area: menu; 
    background-image: url(./images/June\ 21\ -\ 13.JPG);
    background-size: cover;
}
.item3 {
    grid-area: main;  
    background-image: url(./images/DJI_0226.JPG);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.item4 { 
    grid-area: right; 
    background-image: url(./images/June\ 21\ -\ 13.JPG);
    background-size: cover;
}
.item5 { 
    grid-area: footer;
    background-image: url(./images/June\ 21\ -\ 72.JPG);
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px) {


    .grid-gallery{
        display: block;
    }

    .item1 {
        width: 84vw;
        height: 30vh;
        margin-bottom: 4vh;
    }

    .item2 {
        width: 84vw;
        height: 30vh;
        margin-bottom: 4vh;
    }

    .item3 {
        width: 84vw;
        height: 30vh;
        margin-bottom: 4vh;
    }

    .item4 {
        width: 84vw;
        height: 30vh;
        margin-bottom: 4vh;
    }

    .item5 {
        width: 84vw;
        height: 30vh;
        margin-bottom: 4vh;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="gallery-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

    <title>Gallery - Above Photography</title>
</head>
    <body>

        <div id = "hero" class = "center">

            <div id="navBar">

                <img class = "logo" src = "./images/AbovePhotographyLogo.png" alt = "Logo">

                <nav>

                    <ul class = nav__links>

                            <li><a class = "otherPages" href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a class = "page" href="#">Photography</a></li>
                            <li><a class = "otherPages" href="#">Videography</a></li>
                            <li><a class = "otherPages" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <a href="#" ><button class = "bookNowNav">Book Now</button></a>

                    </ul>

                </nav>

            </div>

            <h1>Gallery</h1>
            <p class = "darker-text">The Images Below Are Photos Taken On My Own Time<br>Nobody Hired Me To Take These</p>
            
        </div>  

        <div class="container center">

            <div class="grid-gallery">
                <div class="item1"></div>
                <div class="item2"></div>
                <div class="item3"></div>  
                <div class="item4"></div>
                <div class="item5"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with:

```
.container{
    width: 84vw;
}
```

simply remove that from your CSS and it seems to fix the centering issue.

Comment: That fixes the centering but now, the gallery appears at a very low width.